# Batch insert with UUID error using mybatis in Spring boot with Postgres

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Currently, I am trying to insert some data into through batch process. I have tried insert one by one  and it works flawlessly until when i tried to put foreach in, then thing start to broke out. Please check my below code and error log.

I have a simple test table like below:

```
create table test(name uuid, age int);
```

Here is my mapper class:

```
@Insert("<script>",
            "insert into test (name, age)",
            "values ",
                "<foreach  collection='dmoList' item='dmo' separator=','>",
                    "( #{dmo.name}, #{dmo.age,jdbcType=INTEGER})",
                "</foreach>",
            "</script>")
// i have tried ( #{dmo.name, jdbcType=UUID} but still doesn't work
    int insertBatch(@Param("dmoList") dmoList: List<HashMap<String, Object>):
```

Here is how i invoke this mapper method:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>();
Map data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("name", UUID.randomUUID());
// i have tried to use UUID.randomUUID().toString() but still not working
data.put("age", 12);
list.add(data);
insertBatch(list);
```

And here is the log:

```
2019-09-24 23:54:49.778 ERROR 85464 --- [nio-9082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property '__frch_dmo_0.name'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (java.util.UUID) : jdbcType (null) combination.
### The error may exist in com/cc/fileserver/mapper/FileMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.cc.fileserver.mapper.FileMapper.insertBatch
### The error occurred while executing an update
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property '__frch_dmo_0.name'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (java.util.UUID) : jdbcType (null) combination.] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property '__frch_dmo_0.name'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (java.util.UUID) : jdbcType (null) combination.
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ParameterMapping$Builder.validate(ParameterMapping.java:119) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ParameterMapping$Builder.build(ParameterMapping.java:104) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder$ParameterMappingTokenHandler.buildParameterMapping(SqlSourceBuilder.java:123) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder$ParameterMappingTokenHandler.handleToken(SqlSourceBuilder.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.GenericTokenParser.parse(GenericTokenParser.java:77) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder.parse(SqlSourceBuilder.java:45) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:42) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:297) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.<init>(BaseStatementHandler.java:64) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.<init>(PreparedStatementHandler.java:41) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.<init>(RoutingStatementHandler.java:46) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.newStatementHandler(Configuration.java:592) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:48) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:184) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:271) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:57) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.insertBatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cc.fileserver.service.impl.FileServiceImpl.save(FileServiceImpl.kt:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cc.fileserver.service.impl.ImageServiceImpl.save(ImageServiceImpl.kt:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cc.fileserver.controller.UploadController.uploadFileMulti(UploadController.kt:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `Map` as the parameter, MyBatis cannot detect the type via reflection.
The simplest solution is to specify `typeHandler` explicitly in the parameter reference.

```
#{dmo.name,typeHandler=package.UuidTypeHandler}
```

For completeness, here is the UUID type handler for PostgreSQL which uses `PreparedStatement#setObject()` and `ResultSet#getObject()`.
For other DBs that don't have UUID data type, you may need to use other methods (e.g. `setString()`, `setBytes()`) depending on the database data type you use.

```java
package typehandler;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;

public class UuidTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<UUID> {
  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, UUID parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    ps.setObject(i, parameter);
  }

  @Override
  public UUID getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    return rs.getObject(columnName, UUID.class);
  }

  @Override
  public UUID getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return rs.getObject(columnIndex, UUID.class);
  }

  @Override
  public UUID getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return cs.getObject(columnIndex, UUID.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be part of core's `MyBatis` at this point? I see some types that aren't really part of the `JDBC` being implemented by default (like `InstantTypeHandler`), so adding this one will make working with `UUID`s straightforward, without implementing anything custom.

Comment: @x80486 There is no de facto standard column type for UUID. PostgreSQL has `UUID`, but most other DBs don't. Developers may choose `CHAR` like types or `BINARY(16)` and the methods used in the type handler vary depending on the driver and/or column type (e.g. `set/getString`, `set/getBytes`). So, having one default built-in `UuidTypeHandler` is not a good option at this point.